# Is it possible to cache a dynamic php file with service worker?

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies, service-worker

I am trying to cache the html from a dynamic php-file when logged in (with session-cookie) but the html-file is fetched from the server without the credentials from the session-cookie. (I do not specify a filename in the URL only the path)

```
let cacheName = 'q2';

    let files = [
     '/q/',
     '/q/sw.js',
     '/q/js/main.js',
     '/q/js/init.js',
     '/q/js/lib.js',
     '/q/css/css.css',
     '/q/images/b.jpg',
     '/q/apps/BOK/js/main.js'
    ];


    self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.open(cacheName)
            .then((cache) => {
                return cache.addAll(files)
                .then(() => {
                    console.info('All files are cached');
                    return self.skipWaiting(); 
                })
                .catch((error) =>  {
                    console.error('Failed to cache', error);
                });
            })
        );
    });
```

(I have omitted the self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) )

When I look at the text/html file from '/q/ the service worker has fetched it from the server without the php session cookie PHPSESSID and the contents is therefore wrong.

(Otherwise it works perfect offline)

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is explained in the [Fetch API Specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org).

HTTP cookies (and a few other things) are referred to as "[credentials](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#credentials)".

Whether or not credentials are including in an outgoing HTTP request is determined by the value of the [`credentials` property](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode) of the `Request` object. By default, `credentials` is set to `'omit'`, which leads to the behavior you're seeing. If you want credentials like HTTP cookies included, you need to use `Request` objects whose `credentials` properties are set to `'include'`.

To do this, instead of passing in an array of strings to `cache.addAll()`, you should pass in an array of `Request` objects with the proper `credentials` mode explicitly set. Here's how your code would change:

```
const requestsWithCredentials = [
  '/q/',
  '/q/sw.js',
  '/q/js/main.js',
  '/q/js/init.js',
  '/q/js/lib.js',
  '/q/css/css.css',
  '/q/images/b.jpg',
  '/q/apps/BOK/js/main.js'
].map(url => new Request(url, {credentials: 'include'}));

// Later...
cache.addAll(requestsWithCredentials);
```